# get first X characters from the cat command?

Tags: cat, cut

I have a text file I'm outputting to a variable in my shell script.  I only need the first 50 characters however.

I've tried using `cat ${filename} cut -c1-50` but I'm getting far more than the first 50 characters?  That may be due to `cut` looking for lines (not 100% sure), while this text file could be one long string-- it really depends.

Is there a utility out there I can pipe into to get the first X characters from a `cat` command?

Comment: You forgot a `|`? `cat ${filename} | cut -c1-50`

Comment: @DisplayName fixed, thanks for catching my retyping error.

Comment: @jkj2000, I have reverted back to the older version as that was the original question.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
head -c 50 file
```

This returns the first 50 bytes.

Mind that the command is not always implemented the same on all OS.
On Linux and macOS it behaves this way.
On Solaris (11) you need to use the gnu version in /usr/gnu/bin/

Comment: [head](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) has no `-c` option. I’d go for [dd(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/dd) instead.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that the file contains only ASCII characters, as the OP asked for the first X characters, not bytes.

Comment: @mirabilos It might not be portable, but my version (`GNU coreutils 5.97`) does.

Comment: Yeah, my OS X (BSD) also does.

Comment: POSIX doesn't define `-c` as a valid option, however, so it is definitely dependent on your local environment. http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/head

Comment: @Calimo Yes, I know, but I tried making a text file with 100 characters then running my command and it printed 50 characters. But you're right about ASCII, but since OP flagged this as answered there were none in his case.

Comment: @Yossarian that’s exactly what I’m saying. GNU does. (@DisplayName: OSX uses GNU tools.) But Unix doesn’t.

Comment: @mirabilos 

Yes it does use Some GNU tools, but in this case it does not, running `man head` tells me that it's BSD `head`.

Comment: An overwhelming majority of OS X tools are Unix, maybe 85%.

Comment: [BSD head(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/head) does not have `-c` either.

Comment: `HEAD(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  HEAD(1)

NAME
     head -- display first lines of a file

SYNOPSIS
     head [-n count | -c bytes] [file ...]
`

Comment: I have misunderstood you, I meant FreeBSD,here
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=head

Comment: @DisplayName see, even the BSDs diverge (FreeBSD is often called a "little Linux" in the BSD scene). Anyway, **all** manpages using the `-mdoc` nroff macropackage have, by default, “BSD *something* Manual” on top of them, so that is no indicator. (The presence of this option in FreeBSD _is_, but, as I said, the option is nōn-standard.)

Comment: No they don't, `emacs` and `gcc` for example, say GNU.

Comment: For binary data use `hexdump`; here's my answer containing both `head` and `hexdump`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544247/114401

Answer (score 38):

Your `cut` command works if you use a pipe to pass data to it:

```
cat ${file} | cut -c1-50
```

Or, avoiding a useless use of cat and making it a little safer:

```
cut -c1-50 < "$file"
```

Note that the commands above will print the first 50 characters (or bytes, depending on your `cut` implementation) *of each input line*. It should do what you expect if, as you say, your file is one huge line.

Comment: And if it's not one huge line, simply follow the pipeline with `| head -n1`.

Answer (score 9):

```
dd status=none bs=1 count=50 if=${filename}
```

This returns the first 50 bytes.

Comment: [dd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) has no `status=none` flag. Use `2>/dev/null` instead (and quote properly): `dd if="$filename" bs=1 count=50 2>/dev/null` (even so, consider using `bs=50 count=1` to reduce the number of syscalls involved).

Comment: @mirabilos dd does have `status=none` when using Ubuntu 14.04, coreutils 8.21, but you're right to use `2>/dev/null` if using a earlier version.

Comment: There is no GNU coreutils (nor does [dd(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/dd) have a version) on most Unix systems, which is why I urge you to use the portable version. After all, this is not the “Ask Ubuntu” SO site, but the “Unix & Linux” one.

Comment: @mirabilos Most Linux distros use GNU coreutils as does FreeBSD and other BSDs. It is available on Solaris as package gnu-coreutils. Yes, this is "Unix & Linux" and both Unix and Linux systems use GNU coreutils.

Comment: No, Unix systems do not generally use GNU utilities. GNU is an acronym for “GNU is not Unix”, even. Please stick to portable solutions, or, if you *must* give GNU-only solutions, state so, and, if at all possible, show an equivalent portable solution.

Comment: FreeBSD does not use GNU coreutils. `dd` on recent versions of FreeBSD do however support `status=none` for compatibility with GNU `dd`.

Answer (score 5):

Most answers so far assume that 1 byte = 1 character, which may not be the case if you are using a non-ASCII locale.

A slightly more robust way to do it:

```bsh
testString=$(head -c 200 < "${filename}") &&
  printf '%s\n' "${testString:0:50}"
```

Note that this assumes:

1. You are using `ksh93`, `bash` (or a recent `zsh` or `mksh` (though the only multi-byte charset supported by `mksh` is UTF-8 and only after `set -o utf8-mode`)) and a version of `head` that supports `-c` (most do nowadays, but not strictly standard).
2. The current locale is set to the same encoding as the file (type `locale charmap` and `file -- "$filename"` to check that); if not, set it with ie. `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`)
3. I took the first 200 bytes of the file with `head`, assuming the worst-case UTF-8 where all the characters are encoded on at most 4 bytes. This should cover most cases I can think of.

Comment: Of course, this also assumes GNU `head`, or another implementation of it which adds the nōn-standard `-c` option. But you’re requiring GNU bash already. (Note: `mksh`’s UTF-8 mode could do this for UTF-8 encoded files.) I’d ask the OP if they require octets or multibyte characters, just “characters” is a vague/gerneric term.

Comment: That also assumes `$filename` or `$testString` doesn't contain blank newline or wildcards or start with `-`.

Comment: The `${var:offset:length}` construct you're using here actually comes from `ksh93` and is also supported by recent versions of `zsh` (`zsh` has its own `$testString[1,50]`). You need `${testString:0:50}`  in `ksh93` and `zsh` however.

Comment: Just edited my answer to address the comments above

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -om1 "^.\{50\}" ${filename}
```

Other variant (for first line in file)

```
(IFS= read -r line <${filename}; echo ${line:0:50})
```

Comment: This is abuse of high-level tools – and prone to not doing what you want, e.g. if they’re locale-aware.

Comment: @mirabilos What do you mean under *high-level tools*: `read` and `echo` ? Or `bash expansion` ?

Comment: `grep` (regexp), and yes, the use of shell here (hint: the first line may be large). (That being said, the bashism is also not in POSIX, but most shells implement that.)

Answer (score 1):

### 1. For ASCII files, do [like @DisplayName says:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167816/114401)

```
head -c 50 file.txt
```

will print out the first 50 chars of file.txt, for example.

### 2. For binary data, use `hexdump` to print it out as hex chars:

```
hexdump -n 50 -v file.bin
```

will print out the first 50 bytes of file.bin, for example.

Note that without the `-v` verbose option, `hexdump` would replace repeated lines with an asterisk (`*`) instead. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/494245/what-does-an-asterisk-mean-in-hexdump-output/494613#494613.

Answer (score 1):

To read and output 50 characters (not bytes), with `zsh`, you can do:

```
read -eu0 -k50 < $file
```

If the input contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale, each of those bytes will be counted as one  character.

- `-e`: echoes what is read instead of storing it in a variable:
- `-k50`: reads 50 characters. `read -k` was initially meant for reading key presses on the terminal (and would put the terminal in the correct mode to get one keypress at a time), but when used with `-u<fd>`, it reads characters from the corresponding file descriptor instead.
- `-u0` reads those characters from file descriptor 0 (stdin) which here we redirect from the file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sed` for this which will tackle the problem pretty easily

```bsh
sed -E 's/^(.{0,50}).*/\1/' yourfile
```

`-E` allows us to use **E**xtended regular expressions, instead of basic regular expressions, so we don't have to use backslashes to escape the more advanced regular expression operators.

`s/x/y/` **s**ubstitutes `x` with `y` in each line, where `x` is a regular expression and `y` is an expression which can contain literal values or references to capture groups.

`^(.{0,50})` matches up to the first 50 characters of each line and marks it as a capture group.

`.*` matches the rest of the line (if there were more than 50 characters), since we want to replace the whole thing.

`\1` is a backreference referring to the first capture group.

Comment: Curious to know how this got downvoted if it solves the OP's question: "I only need the first 50 characters" This accomplishes what was requested without UUOC (Useless Use of Cat)

Comment: This answer gives the first fifty characters of each line in the file, not just the first 50 of the file. Also doesn't print anything at all if all the lines are less than 50 characters long. Your solution would work better with `sed -n -e '1s/^\(.\{50\}\).*/\1/p' ${filename}`

Comment: Understood could have just: head -n 1 | sed -e 's/^\(.\{50\}\).*/\1/' ... And it would have solved the issue. OP stated: "only need the first 50 characters"

Comment: Nope. If the first line is only 49 characters long it would output nothing.

Comment: Doug I understood this the first time around yet the OP mentioned nothing about printing if the line contained less than 50 chars, so I still fail to see your point, nor the point of this being downvoted since again it fell into what would have worked with head: head -n 1 ${filename} | sed -n -e '1s/^\(.\{50\}\).*/\1/p'

Comment: If the file contains 100 lines, each being 10 characters long, then your solution prints nothing. The OP would like to see the first 5 lines of this file. In the case where the entire file is only 49 characters long it is unclear if the OP wants to see nothing or wants to see all characters up to a limit of 50 characters.

Comment: As a non-linux `sed` expert, yet a software developer, this answer, without a detailed explanation to accompany it, is ridiculous. And to use the word "easily" in how you describe the use of this command is equally comical.

Comment: In my testing, `.{n}` in `sed` will capture lines even if they are less than `n` characters in length, even though that's not to spec. However, even if this weren't the case, this answer would only need the slight alteration of `.{0,50}` to do the job. The answer's score is a bit harsh. I'll submit an edit.

Comment: @GabrielStaples this answer (before I edited it) was no less confusing than most of the other answers, especially if you have a basic understanding of regular expressions, which is a very important skill to have as a developer, because they're so useful even if just searching through your code or making batch replacements. Calling it ridiculous was unwarranted.

Comment: @philraj, thanks for the clarification. That's very helpful for people.

Comment: @munkeyoto, if you 1) point out in your answer that this solution returns the first 50 characters **of each line**, not just the first 50 chars of the entire file, and 2) also present an alternative solution, in addition to the one you currently have, to just print out the first 50 chars of the entire file, whether or not they span multiple lines, then I will upvote this answer. It has its merits for sure.